# Conditional react attributes

Tags: reactjs

I've had a look at some other posts but nothing seems to address only including an attribute if a condition is met rather than give another value if the condition is false.

I'm trying to only add an attribute if a condition is met. Take this for example:

```
<input {{true && id='test'}} type='text'/>
```

I've just put true instead of the real condition for ease, so this input should have an id of true. What is the workaround for this?

Comment: I've had luck using ternaries outside if the element, something like this:
`const attribute = true ? {id: test} : {}; <input {...attribute}/>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
<input type='text' {...(condition ? {id: 'test'} : {})} />
```

Comment: perfect, that method work withs with &&. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can also do:

```
<input {...(hello && { id: 'test' })} />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
const props = {
  type: 'text'
}

if (condition) props.id = 'test'

return <input {...props} />
```